# Why are areas sometimes negative?

Tags: analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

In coordinage geometry, sometimes calculating the area of a triangle, parallelogram, or any n-sided figure gives you a negative result. What is the reason behind this, and is there some known method to always get a positive result?

Comment: Take whatever formula you are using, and put absolute value signs around it – then you'll always get a nonnegative result.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the source where you are seeing negative areas? In general, areas and lengths should not be negative, but they can be if they are directed.

Comment: Signed area can help you tell if a transformation has a reflection component in linear algebra. They arise naturally for computational reasons but typically you just scrub the sign to get the actual area.

Answer (score 0):

This is just the concept of orientation. For example: If you have two vectors $v = (v_1, v_2), w = (w_1, w_2) \in \mathbb R^2$ then the area of the parallelogram with vertices $0, v, v+w, w$ is given through $\det(v, w) = \det\begin{pmatrix} v_1 & w_1 \\ v_2 & w_2 \end{pmatrix}$. If you exchange $v$ and $w$ (remember, the determinant is multilinear and alternating), you get $\det(v, w) = -\det(w, v)$.

So just take the absolute value if you like to: $\lvert\det(v, w)\rvert = \lvert\det(w, v)\rvert$.